# DISM and Dependencies

Tags: windows, dism

Is there a way to list out dependencies for each feature that you want to install via DISM?

E.g. if I wanted to install IIS-ASPNET, I will need to install IIS-BasicAuthentication and IIS-Core (or whatever their dependencies are)

The last thing I want to do is to work this all out by hand!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of Windows? Here are the packages/features available in Windows 7 that relate to IIS, presented as a reverse dependency tree (children require their parent to be installed, because this is how the source presented it, and I don't have time to invert it right now):

```
IIS-HostableWebCore
IIS-WebServerRole
 +-IIS-FTPServer
 |  +-IIS-FTPExtensibility
 |  +-IIS-FTPSvc
 |  `-IIS-FTPExtensibility
 +-IIS-WebServer
 |  +-IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
 |  |  +-IIS-ASP
 |  |  +-IIS-ASPNET
 |  |  +-IIS-CGI
 |  |  +-IIS-ISAPIExtensions
 |  |  |  +-IIS-ASP
 |  |  |  +-IIS-ASPNET
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-ISAPIFilter
 |  |  |  `-IIS-ASPNET
 |  |  +-IIS-NetFxExtensibility
 |  |  |  +-IIS-ASPNET
 |  |  |  +-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  |  `-WCF-HTTP-Activation
 |  |  `-IIS-ServerSideIncludes
 |  +-IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
 |  |  +-IIS-DefaultDocument
 |  |  |  +-IIS-ASPNET
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-DirectoryBrowsing
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-HttpErrors
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-HttpRedirect
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-StaticContent
 |  |  |  +-IIS-WebDAV
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  `-IIS-WebDAV
 |  +-IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
 |  |  +-IIS-CustomLogging
 |  |  +-IIS-HttpLogging
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-HttpTracing
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-LoggingLibraries
 |  |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  |  +-IIS-ODBCLogging
 |  |  `-IIS-RequestMonitor
 |  |     `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  +-IIS-Performance
 |  |  +-IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic
 |  |  `-IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
 |  |     `-MSMQ-HTTP
 |  `-IIS-Security
 |     +-IIS-BasicAuthentication
 |     +-IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
 |     +-IIS-DigestAuthentication
 |     +-IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication
 |     +-IIS-IPSecurity
 |     +-IIS-RequestFiltering
 |     |  +-IIS-ASP
 |     |  `-IIS-NetFxExtensibility
 |     |     +-IIS-ASPNET
 |     |     `-WCF-HTTP-Activation
 |     +-IIS-URLAuthorization
 |     `-IIS-WindowsAuthentication
 `-IIS-WebServerManagementTools
    +-IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
    |  +-IIS-LegacyScripts
    |  +-IIS-LegacySnapIn
    |  +-IIS-Metabase
    |  |  +-IIS-LegacyScripts
    |  |  +-IIS-LegacySnapIn
    |  |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
    |  `-IIS-WMICompatibility
    |     `-IIS-LegacyScripts
    +-IIS-ManagementConsole
    |  `-MSMQ-HTTP
    +-IIS-ManagementScriptingTools
    `-IIS-ManagementService
```

<sup>[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716257.aspx)</sup>

Comment: It was mainly any windows that used DISM (7 and 8 at work), thanks!

Comment: How did you work out this tree?

Comment: @nebffa Check the source link beneath the tree. Package paths are named `A\B\C\PackageName`, where `PackageName` requires packages `C`, `B`, and `A` to be installed as well.